# Проблемы в реализации программы СИ

Tags: c

В двумерном масиве наполненом рандомными цыфрами надо найти максимумы строк,а потом среди этих максимумов найти минимальное значение и его координаты в масиве.Проблема заключается в том что я не могу реализовать вывод координат для минимума среди максимумов строк,прошу вашей помощи.Заранее спасибо.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
    int array[20][20] = { 0 };
    int N, A, B;
    A = -20;
    B = 20;
    int min = 21;
    int S = 0;
    int F = 0;
    printf("Enter number of elements ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)

        {
            array[i][j] = rand() % (B - A + 1) + A;



            printf("%5d", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int max = -21;


        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = array[i][j];
         
                if (array[i][j] < min)
                {
                    S = i;
                    F = j;
                }
            }

        }

        if (max < min)
        {
            min = max;
        }
        printf("\n Maximal element is %d ", max);
    }
    printf("\n Minimal element  is %d [%d] [%d] ", min,S,F);
}
```

Comment: В плане не можете? Неправильно выводятся или что?

Comment: Да,само число показывает чётко,а его координаты нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример кода с комментариями об ошибках, которые у вас были. Если есть вопросы не стесняйтесь задавать:

```
int F = 0; //Индекс столбика максимального элемента 
int resS = 0, resF = 0; //Координаты минимального максимума строк
//Нужно проходит не от 0 до 10, а от 0 до N. 
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int max = -21;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        //Находим максимум в строке
        if (array[i][j] > max) {
            max = array[i][j];
            //Сохраняя его столбец
            F = j;
        }
    }

    //После того как нашли максимум в строке
    //сравним с min чтобы найти минимальный максимум
    if (array[i][F] < min) {
        //Сохраняем координаты 
        resS = i;
        resF = F;
        min = array[i][F];
    }

    printf("\n Maximal element is %d ", max);
}

printf("\n Minimal element  is %d [%d] [%d] ", min, resS, resF);
```

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался и всё исправил